# Functions for Finding Out the Midpoint (Interpolation)

Tags: r

I am interested in solving this kind of problem (interpolation/midpoint) :

[image]

Suppose I have this kind of data (I randomly generated data, it might not exactly fit this set up):

```
x1 = runif(100)
x2 = x1+ runif(100)
y1 = runif(100)
y2 = y1 + runif(100)
z1 = y2 -  (runif(100)/3)

interpolation_data = data.frame(x1, x2, y1, y2, z1)

> head(interpolation_data)

          x1        x2        y1        y2        z1
1 0.98851249 1.8413195 0.5362105 0.6490267 0.4130697
2 0.87617261 0.9825167 0.5628463 0.9246420 0.7357799
3 0.05901131 0.4298880 0.2463369 1.1585020 1.0614156
4 0.26843176 0.6694523 0.9467490 1.1860874 1.0859276
5 0.86021705 1.4767606 0.9956568 1.2048599 1.1932450
6 0.19368972 0.2269496 0.7618794 0.9763212 0.8594290
```

I want to write to calculate a value of Z2 for each row. I did this myself:

```
interpolation_data$z2 = (interpolation_data$x1 + ((interpolation_data$z1 - interpolation_data$y1) * (interpolation_data$x2 - interpolation_data$x1)))/(interpolation_data$y2 - interpolation_data$y1)
```

- Are there any built-in ways in R to do this? I tried looking for something and nothing came up that exactly matched this kind of problem.

Thank you!

Comment: There's a function [`LearnGeom::MidPoint `](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/LearnGeom/html/MidPoint.html) in a CRAN package.

Comment: Your method does not work. Since your x and y values are random, they do not increase like your figure. On the first row z1 does not lie between y1 and y2 and the computed z2 value is 7.8, far outside the plot boundaries.